# Parameter in Parse Cloud Success function:

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Here are three separated examples in Parse cloud Code guide: My question is about the "success" in the three examples: The parameters of these two success function, "list", "object" and "results": I didn't find them in the rest of the code. How they been passed to the function? Are they newly created variables? How does the success function work? (I am new to JavaScript)

```
 var query = relation.query();
 query.equalTo("title", "I'm Hungry");
 query.find({
    success:function(list) {
 }
 });


var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("playerEmail", "dstemkoski@example.com");
query.first({
   success: function(object) {
   // Successfully retrieved the object.
 },
    error: function(error) {
alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
 }
});


var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.find({
   success: function(results) {
      alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
      // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
   }
 },
 error: function(error) {
   alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `success` functions are callbacks. So, your question comes logically:

What is a callback?

Well, when you send a request from the client-side to the server, the server will handle the request and send back the response. However, client-side must have a handler for the event when the request successfully returned the response. This kind of event is the callback. The parameter of the callback is the effective response from the server.

Now, you had two calls for `find` and a call for `first`.

`.find` sends the query and expects to get the list of resulting records as a response.

`.first` sends the query and expects to get the first record which matches the criteria.

You have a `query`, where you expect results which have the title of `"I'm Hungry"`. The parameter called `list` should hold those values (you can have any names for your callback parameters).

Next, you expect to have an `object` having a playerEmail of `"dstemkoski@example.com"`. You are calling `first`, because email should be unique and you want to optimize the query on server-side and handle a singe object instead of a list on client-side.

Finally, you query by playerName, matching `"Dan Stemkoski"` and you expect the `results` to hold the players matching that name.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation! I have some additional questions. What if the function returns two results instead of one? Should I use two parameters to hold? If that, what is the order of passing values from the results?

Comment: If you have more than one result, then the list sent to the client-side should hold more elements, so a single parameter should be enough.

Comment: Cool, i really appreciate your help. If it is not too much trouble, could you help me with this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712446/parse-cloud-code-helper-function-not-working

Comment: It is not too much trouble, but this deserves to be a separate question. You need to describe the data-source used at the server to enable us to help you further